# How to import js/html files using a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a `themes.js` file whose helper is as follows:

```
Template.themes.helpers({
        'allcompanyInformation' : function() {

            var configData = CompanySettings.findOne({"_id" : "dNtMroDWtaKQytD6W"});
            if(configData){
            console.log(configData);
            console.log(configData.generalSettings.storeType);

                 switch(configData.generalSettings.storeType){
                    case 'AutomobileSpares':
                        console.log("AutomobileSpares");
                        import './autospare-inhouse-theme/autospare-inhouse-theme.js';
                        break;

                    case 'FashionJwellery':
                        console.log("FashionJwellery");
                        import './classic-jwellery-themes/classic-jwellery-themes.js';
                        break;

                    case 'PreciousJwellery':
                            if(configData.generalSettings.processType =='Customize'){
                                if(configData.generalSettings.shopType =='inhouse'){
                                console.log(configData.generalSettings.shopType);   
                                console.log("***  In inhouse ***");
                                import '../modules/homepage/homepage.js';
                                import './elegant-jwellery-theme/elegant-jwellery-theme.js';


                            }
                            else{
                                console.log("if not inhouse");
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("ProcessType else part");
                        }
                        break;  

                    case 'GroceryStore':
                        import './modern-grocery-theme/modern-grocery-theme.js';
                        break;
                 }
            }


        },
    });
```

I want to import `import '../modules/homepage/homepage.js';` if conditions of switch are satisfied. This must render `homepage.html`, which is imported by `homepage.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello have you tried `require()` instead of `import`?

As per the meteor [guide](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#using-require) you shall use `require` for imports that aren't at the top-level of your module.

E.g. in your case substitute:

`import '../modules/homepage/homepage.js';`

with:

`require('../modules/homepage/homepage.js');`

An do so for all the other nested `import` statements.